# matplotlib widgets rectangleselector

Tags: python, matplotlib, widget

In Python 2.7 the rectangle selector does what it should: it returns in "eclick" the click position and in "erelease" the position of the mouse release. This is no longer the case with Python 3.6. There the selector returns in eclick the lower left corner coordinate and in erelease the upper right corner of the rectangle. This looks particularly nasty, if the drawmode='line' is chosen, because the "unconventional" behavior is already reflected in the latent line which does not follow the mouse, but shows the principal diagonal of the imaginary rectangle. Shall this inconsistent handling become a feature?

Comment: Is the question how to get a desired behaviour in python 3, or do you want to know if the inconsistent behaviour is a bug? In the latter case, asking this at the git issue tracker is probably better. In the former case, which behaviour would you like to see?

Comment: It's both. Perhaps somebody knows a simple way (perhaps a keyword) to prevent the RectangleSelector from "normalizing" the mouse coordinate input. Then I would not have to write my own module based on the public sources. And, second, I consider this behavior a bug, because it reduces the usability of the RectangleSelector. If somebody needs to normalize (as I sometimes need for specific input), then it is a very simple task which can be done by the user. As I am new to Python, I thank you for the hint to consider the "git issue tracker".